# How to access style sheets and js files from public folder using Laravel Framework

Tags: laravel

[http://blog.com/assests/bower_components/bootstrap/dist//bootstrap.min.css

Above have mentioned the path to css directory

Comment: use {{ asset('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/bootstrapmin.css') }}

Comment: add this to script  URL::asset('path/to/filename'

Answer (score 0):

you can use the URL facade like

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('path/to/your.file') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the "asset()" helper of Laravel, however, the path is indicated from the **config/filesystems.php** file and the default mode is the "public"

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

The **root** key here points to the storage of your files such as the css, js, images and other stuff, so by default, it points to your "storage/app/public" of your Laravel project

Example code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">

In your case it should be like this
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assests/bower_components/bootstrap/dist//bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are example on how you can map your files from your Laravel's public folder.

```
public
|----->css
|----->bower_components
       |----->bootstrap
              |----->dist
                     |----->css
                     |      |------>bootstrap.min.css
                     |      |------>bootstrap.css
                     |----->js
                            |------>bootstrap.min.js
                            |------>bootstrap.js
```

Then you can access them like so:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{ asset('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('assests/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

OR

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('assests/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css') }}"></script>
```